# Tableau data blending how does the column from secondary data source work?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have 2 data sources, A and B, they are linked by data blending with A.id = B.id, A.order_date = B.order_date. Both fields are linked in worksheet.

when I use A as primary data source and drag A.amount into the view, it gives me the correct sum. However when I use B as primary data source, drag [A].[amount] into the view, it gives less than the correct amount.

Does anyone here have any clue why is that? and how will I be able to use B as primary data source to retrieve A.amount?

Answer (score 0):

Use LOD for the calculation. While blending the data sources there is a chance for duplication. So to get rid of this use an LOD with the granular fields from respective datasource for the metric.

eg:
{fixed id,order_date: max(amount)}

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Blends works same as left join, so depending on which table you set as "primary", your results may be different.